# How can I position an element to bottom of browser window and only showing content when scrolling?

Tags: javascript, jquery

On the website in the link below, the Logo stays on the bottom of the page when the window ist resized and the content beneath isn't visable till you scroll the site up or down. This works on mobile devices too.
How can I manage it to position a DIV to the bottom of the browserwindow so that the following DIV is hidden until you begin to scroll? 
Here is a Link of a Site that shows exactly what I would like to reprogramm.

[Please visit this Site as an example](http://www.alpenhof.co.at/)

Thanks in advance

Comment: By "logo" do you mean the scroll-to-top icon?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Show "Back to top" link element using jQuery when you scroll down](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5980237/show-back-to-top-link-element-using-jquery-when-you-scroll-down)

Answer (score 1):

CSS:

```
#element {
display: none;
/* and other CSS */
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).on("scroll", function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) { /* change the integer to whatever you need */
        $("#element").fadeIn("slow");
    } else {
        $("#element").fadeOut("slow");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First, the element has fixed positioning and is hidden:

```
#dynamic-to-top {
    display: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: auto;
    z-index: 90;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    top: auto;
    left: auto;
    ...
```

Then, a jQuery function listens for the scroll event. It appears that a calculation is done to see whether the page has scrolled downward past a certain point. Many examples of this behavior exist [**on SO**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5980237/show-back-to-top-link-element-using-jquery-when-you-scroll-down) and the web.